How can I update a field on a Contact from its Converted Lead? It was missed in mapping
I have thousands of Contacts.
There were about 20 or so custom fields on the Lead that involved marketing.
These were mapped to Contact so they could be tracked all the way through. Two days ago sales needed to report on one of them. It happens to be the one field that was overlooked and not mapped.
So, now I have mapped it. But, I need to see if I can get that information to populate.
From this post: Can I get lead Id on converted contact record? Is there any standard field on contact which shows lead id?
I created a LeadId field that maps from Lead to contact so in the future I can query converted Leads from the Contact.
But, that doesn't help me now.
The furthest I have gotten is to query the Lead records I need:
SELECT Id, Name, UTM_Term__c FROM Lead WHERE IsConverted=true AND UTM_Term__c != null
I initially thought I might use a flow to update the UTM field but I can't do that without the LeadId to connect the Contact to the Lead. The only field I can seem to find is contactCreatedByLead, which according to documentation is null and only serves to show it was created from a Lead.
Any ideas? I can find my way around SOQL and some apex but I am not a developer, but always willing to learn more.

ConvertedContactId field on Lead object points to the source Contact. You can build a flow that will pull all leads that came from conversion but are missing your field, then update it based on source Contact.

Perfect!  I ended up having chatGPT help write some apex because I have a lot of records. I am not quite up to speed on utilizing Map and that is what I needed to map the ConvertedContactId as the key and the Lead as the value. From there it was a matter of querying the contacts based on the map, then a loop to update fields.
Worked perfectly in the sandbox. What is weird is that no searching brought that field up. And chatGPT wanted to use ConvertedLeadId, close but no cigar.
Thank you for the help!

If this is a one-time update for existing converted records, you can just export the converted Leads with the ConvertedContactId field and the missing field, then update the Contacts using id field.

Thank you @DavidCheng. Part of my motivation was to attempt to do some things programmatically rather than via export/update. This sort of thing in particular. Even with being slow with producing the code this process, minus posting the question, was quicker.
